# Looking for information about going to Mikvah with an IUD

Tags: halacha, technology, niddah

I am interested in going to a Mikvah for the first time.  I have an intrauterine device (aka IUD, a form of birth control) and get very little or sometimes no bleeding.  I don't now how to determine when I should go to the Mikvah.  Whom should I consult to get this information?

Comment: Amy, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please note that Mi Yodeya [cannot offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) you personal practical advice. I recommend that you [consult your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) to determine how to proceed. I wish you the best of success in your observance of the laws of family purity and in navigating their tricky intersection with modern medicine.

Comment: In addition to a rabbi you might also consider the ladies in charge of a mikvah close to your home, see http://mikvah.org/directory for some contacts. My guess is they will advise you to come asap and for sure before your next relation but I'm not that knowledgeable about the relevant laws. Congratulations on taking this crucial mitzvah.